# Single query for several selects -even if one select returns empty

Tags: mysql, select, ifnull

I need to make several select statements to get simple data (**only one row** containing **one or several fields** for each select).

Simplified example:

```
select name, price from article where id=125
select log, email from user where uid=241
```

**I want to process only one single statement from php side** (or: I do NOT want to prepare several statements, execute several statements, catch and handle exceptions for each execution and finally fetch result for each statement...).
I tried:

```
select * from (
  (select name, price from article where id=125) as a,
  (select log, email from user where uid=241) as b
)
```

which works great if every subselect returns values:

```
name  |  price  | log  | email
------------------------------------------
dummy |  12,04  | john | john@example.com
```

But **if one of the subselects returns empty, the whole select returns empty**.
What I want is: null values for empty resulting subselects.
I tried many things with `ifnull()` and `coalesce()`, but couldn't get the awaited result (I know how to use them with null values, but I didn't find a way to deal with them in the case of an empty result set).
I finally found a solution with left joins:

```
select * from (
  (select 1) as thisWillNeverReturnEmpty
  left join (select name, price from article where id=125) as a on 1
  left join (select log, email from user where uid=241) as b on 1
)
```

which works perfectly even if one of the subqueries returns empty (or even both, therefore the "select 1").
Another way I found on SO would be to add a `count(*)` in each subquery to make sure there's a value.

But it all looks quite dirty and I can't believe there's no simple way just using something like `ifnull()`.
What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Did you tried with `UNION select... UNION select ...`?

Comment: Thanks. But the different queries won't necessary have the same types, neither the same number of fields. And I'm not quite clear abt how I could know which row belongs to which query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I finally found was:

```
select * from (
  (select count(*) as nbArt, name, price from article where id=125) as a,
  (select count(*) as nbUser, log, email from user where uid=241) as b
)
```

This way, no subquery ever returns empty, which solves the problem (there's always at least a "zero" count followed by null values).

Sample result when no article is found:

```
nbArt  |  name  |  price  |  nbUser  |  log  |  email
----------------------------------------------------------------
  0    |  null  |   null  |    1     |  john | john@example.com
```